# Firebase Android How to push data from Model class itself

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to push an Object of a class to Firebase by defining the function in that class itself, but I am getting **stackOverflow** error. I am using native datatypes in the class and a Firebase reference object.

The database structure I am using is as follows:
[image: Firebase Structure]

I have created Model Class for **Orders** as follows:

```
public class Orders {
private String billNo;
private String custId;
private String dateAndTime;
private int personCount;
private int status;
private int table;
private String orderId;
private boolean AC=true;

public String getBillNo() {
    return billNo;
}

public void setBillNo(String billNo) {
    this.billNo = billNo;
}

public String getCustId() {
    return custId;
}

public void setCustId(String custId) {
    this.custId = custId;
}

public String getDateAndTime() {
    return dateAndTime;
}

public void setDateAndTime(String dateAndTime) {
    this.dateAndTime = dateAndTime;
}

public int getPersonCount() {
    return personCount;
}

public void setPersonCount(int personCount) {
    this.personCount = personCount;
}

public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public int getTable() {
    return table;
}

public void setTable(int table) {
    this.table = table;
}

public String getOrderId() {
    return orderId;
}

public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
    this.orderId = orderId;
}


private DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


public Orders(String orderId, String billNum, String customerId, String date, int personCnt, int status, int tableNo, boolean AC){
    this.billNo = billNum;
    this.custId = customerId;
    this.dateAndTime = date;
    this.personCount = personCnt;
    this.status = status;
    this.table = tableNo;
    this.orderId= orderId;

    Log.v("Orders","I am in Orders");
}

public Orders(){

}

public void pushOrder(){

    Log.v("PushOrdersId",this.getOrderId());
    String OId = this.getOrderId();

    mDatabase.child("Orders").child(OId).setValue(Orders.this);

}
}
```

Then I have created its **child class Items** as follows:

```
public class Items extends Orders {
private String itemId;
private int qty;

DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Orders");

public Items(String orderId, String billNum, String customerId, String date, int personCnt, int status, int tableNo, boolean AC) {
    super(orderId, billNum, customerId, date, personCnt, status, tableNo, AC);
//        this.itemId = itemId;
//        this.qty = qty;
        Log.v("Items","I am in Items child");

}

public Items() {
}

public String getItemId() {
    return itemId;
}

public void setItemId(String itemId) {
    this.itemId = itemId;
}

public int getQty() {
    return qty;
}

public void setQty(int qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
}

//    public void push(HashMap<String, Items> items){
//        for (Items item: items.values()) {
//            String itemKey = mRef.child(this.getOrderId()).child("items").push().getKey();
//
//            mRef.child(this.getOrderId()).child("items").child(itemKey).setValue(item);
//        }
//    }
}
```

And then I am calling a function PushOrders from Class Orders in another class:

```
nm=name.getText().toString();
                mob=mobile.getText().toString();
                seat=seats.getText().toString();
                email=emailID.getText().toString();


                    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Orders");
                    String orderTd = mDatabase.push().getKey();
                    custId = id;

                    itemsHashMap = new HashMap<>();

//                        itemsArrayMap.put("itemid","1");
//                        itemsArrayMap.put("quantity","2");
                    dateAndTime = new Date();
                    personCount=Integer.parseInt(seat);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), orderTd, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                    Items item = new Items(orderTd,billNo, custId, dateAndTime.toString(), personCount, status, table, AC);

                    item.pushOrder();
//                        item.push(itemsHashMap);


                }
```

I was able to figure out the following line in class Orders is giving the error, but couldn't figure out why? and how to resolve it.

```
mDatabase.child("Orders").child(OId).setValue(Orders.this);
```

> Error log

```
10-05 09:37:34.239 28265-28265/dyncardview.abpss.com E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: dyncardview.abpss.com, PID: 28265 java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF
```

Can anyone please help me out in this case?

Comment: put your error log here.

Comment: Error Log: `10-05 09:37:34.239 28265-28265/dyncardview.abpss.com E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: dyncardview.abpss.com, PID: 28265
                                                                       java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF`

Comment: The reason is  
DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Orders"); and mDatabase.child("Orders").child(OId).setValue(Orders.this); is it perfect?

Comment: you are trying to getReference("Orders") and adding mDatabase.child("Orders") same node.

Comment: private DatabaseReference mDatabase =
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Orders").child("Orders");  //considering same child name as table name.


Then use this,
 mDatabase.child(OId).setValue(Orders.this);

Comment: But mDatabase object refers to different references in Orders class and the class where the function is called. According to me that should not make any difference. Still let me check by renaming the database reference object in the class.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but still getting same error.

Comment: Try this and let me know.     private DatabaseReference mDatabase =
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Orders");  
//getting a unique id using push().getKey() method,
           String id =  mDatabase.push().getKey();
            Orders model = new Orders(id , name ,other data ....);
            //Saving the model,
            mDatabase.child(id).setValue(model);

Comment: I will try it and will let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes in your code according to your firebase DB Structure,

```
//Set order data
Orders orders=new Orders();
orders.setBillNo("123");
orders.setCustId("12");
orders.setDateAndTime(new Date().toString());
orders.setPersonCount(13);
orders.setStatus(2);
orders.setTable(2);
orders.setOrderId("23");
orders.setAC(true);

//Add items to order
List<Items> itemsList=new ArrayList<Items>();
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    Items items=new Items();
    items.setItemId("55");
    items.setQty(i);
    itemsList.add(items);
}
orders.setItems(itemsList);

DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Orders");
mRef.push().setValue(orders);
```

Your **Order** class

```
public class Orders {
    private String billNo;
    private String custId;
    private String dateAndTime;
    private int personCount;
    private int status;
    private int table;
    private String orderId;
    private boolean AC = true;
    private List<Items> items;
    //Generate getter and setters other code
}
```

Item Class

```
public class Items {
    private String itemId;
    private int qty;
    //Generate getter and setters other code
}
```

You can fetch order using order key with complete items (You will get complete item list inside your order)

```
DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Orders").child(yourOrderKey);
mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
             Orders orders=postSnapshot.getValue(Orders.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but I think you have removed the parent-child relation between Orders and Items. This will cause trouble when I will try to fetch items related to particular Order. I think so.

Comment: Ok. I will try doing this and let you know the resuls.

Comment: @ChaitanyaAmbardekar I just made changes in `addValueEventListener` `onDataChange()` method

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that and will let you know.

Comment: @ChaitanyaAmbardekar sure

Comment: No... Your code is not working... Being child, Items in Orders, from Firebase, are of type HashMap where our odel accepts List... So we are getting error that Invvalid assignment

Answer (score 0):

After creating an Instance of Firebase DB you just have to write the code snippet below:

User users = new User(userID, name, edtEmail.getText().toString().trim(), edtContactNumber.getText().toString().trim());
    //saving data onto database
    mDatabase.child("user").child(userID).setValue(users);

You can change the model and data as per requirement

Comment: can you pl explain it more! how it will work? I guess he did the same code.

Comment: The problem is in the table named "order" there is a unique key in which "Items" model is there, The values are to be extracted from "Items" not orders and even while saving the data the process should be same